# Adding multiple values for a single attribute in HTML

Tags: html

I just got this map that uses this line:

```
<li  title="restaurant" id="restaurant" name="japanese">Japanese Restaurant</li>
```

to search show all places that has the keyword "Japanese" in it's name. What I want is to add one or more keywords into the string. The following WRONG code gives you an idea what I mean:

```
<li  title="restaurant" id="restaurant" name="japanese+sushi">Japanese Restaurant</li>
```

I'm wondering if this is possible somehow?
Thanks

Comment: No. Any given attribute can appear only once in an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Also, `name` is not a valid attribute for a `li`.

See more about which attributes are allowed on a `li` element [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html).